# Changing option strict value on all the jobs under a Rundeck project

Tags: ansible, edit, rundeck

I've been using rundeck to run ansible playbooks on several remote hosts. My current structure is one rundeck project per host. I've been importing the project's configuration and jobs from one project to another so I don't have to set everything manually for each one.

I'm looking for a way to bulk edit a variable/option on al the project's jobs without having to manually edit each one. For instance, I have the option "target" which has a strict value that matches the remote host that's supposed to run the playbook. Since I'm importing all the jobs from a previous project to a new one, I need to change the strict value of the option "target" on the new project.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Can you share structure as a tree for better visualization?

Comment: The best approach to "automate" that is to use an script (calling the [API](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/rundeck-api.html) or using [RD-CLI](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/learning/howto/learn-rd-cli.html#learn-the-rundeck-cli)) that gets the current job definition, edits the xml/yaml file and then re-upload to your instance in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help! I was able to accomplish what I was looking for by following the suggestion made by @MegaDrive68k. I created an Ansible playbook to use the RD-CLI to modify all the jobs. It looks like this:

```
---
- name: "Replacing Target Host"
  hosts: localhost
  any_errors_fatal: true
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  vars_prompt:
    - name: "rundeck_project"
      prompt: "Rundeck project"
      private: no
    - name: "old_target"
      prompt: "Old target name"
      private: no
    - name: "new_target"
      prompt: "New target name"
      private: no

  tasks:

  - block:

    - name: "Listing all jobs from a Rundeck project"
      shell: "rd jobs list --project {{ rundeck_project }} | awk '{print $1}' | tail -n +2"
      register: invar_jobs_id

    - name: "Store jobs in a yaml file"
      shell: "rd jobs list --project {{ rundeck_project }} -i {{ item }} -f /path/to/the/directory/{{ item }}.yml -F yaml"
      loop: "{{ invar_jobs_id.stdout_lines }}"
      register: invar_jobs_file

    - name: "Replace target"
      shell: "sed -i 's/{{ old_target }}/{{ new_target }}/g' /path/to/the/directory/{{ item.stdout_lines[0] | regex_search('(?<=/path/to/the/directory/).*\\.yml') }}"
      loop: "{{ invar_jobs_file.results }}"

    - name: "Import jobs from yaml files to Rundeck"
      shell: "rd jobs load -p {{ rundeck_project }}  -f /path/to/the/directory/{{ item.stdout_lines[0] | regex_search('(?<=/path/to/the/directory/).*\\.yml') }} -F yaml"
      loop: "{{ invar_jobs_file.results }}"

    always:

    - name: "Removing files"
      shell: "rm -rf /path/to/the/directory/*"
```

Note you must define the env variables RD_URL and RD_TOKEN in order for the Rundeck commands to access and modify the information of your Rundeck projects.